# Why do i need -d option on this cut command?

Tags: linux, options

I have one txt file called sales.txt

```
Fred apples 20 April 4
Susy oranges 5 April 7
Mark watermelons 12 April 10
Terry peaches 7 April 15
```

And when i use this command:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 bash-tut]# cat sales.txt | cat /dev/stdin | cut -d' ' -f 2,3 | sort
20 April
oranges 5
peaches 7
watermelons 12
```

The point is if i remove the -d' ' part, i got all the field of the text file.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 bash-tut]# cat sales.txt | cat /dev/stdin | cut -f 2,3 | sort
Mark watermelons 12 April 10
pples 20 April 4
Susy oranges 5 April 7
Terry peaches 7 April 15
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 bash-tut]# man cut
```

Why was that? I was looking up for d option on man page and it said: -d just mean field delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page on my system says:

```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```

So if you don't specify `-d`, `cut` assumes that your fields are separated by `TAB` characters.  Your input file contains no `TAB` characters.  Meanwhile, the man page also says:

```
   -f, --fields=LIST
          select only these fields;  also print any line that contains  no
          delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

The key part there is "also print any line that contains no delimiter character".  This is what you have: every line in your file contains "no delimiter character".

Comment: Ah i got it, just created a new text file with each filed delimited by TAB and i didn't have to use -d option anymore. Thank you!